# Transform rotate bug with svg

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a problem and I would like to have your opinion on it, I want to Retate () with Transform on an svg with this.

```
<SlideG onClick={(event)=> {
        let transform = event.target.style.transform;
        event.target.style.transform =  (transform == "") ? "rotate(180deg)" : "";
    }}></SlideG>
```

It works almost perfectly .... Unfortunately the svg becomes  invisible after clicking on it, a number of faith for no apparent reason.

do you have any idea why?
Thank.

Comment: share the full code please or Fiddle as it is hard to visualise

Comment: For what i see here I think your problem reside in passing tranform 'empty' in the style.  try instead of "rotate(180deg)" : "";      use : "rotate(180deg)" : "none";

Comment: SVGs rotate about a 0 0 point which differs  from other elements which use 50% 50%, their central point, so your SVG is probably getting rotated out of the viewport.